# Adjust UITableViewCell height according to the resizing label

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. In UITableViewCell's `contentView` i have added a `UIButton` and below button there is a `UILabel` (Button and UILabel are siblings to each other).

In the start there will no text on the UILabel and so its height constraint is set to >= 0. but When i tap the button, i set the text property of the `UILabel`, and it should become visible. In other words i want to expand the height of the UILabel and also height of UITableViewCell should be expanded.

I have pinned `UIButton` `Top,Leading` and `Trailing` edges to `UITableViewCell` `contentView` and similarly i have pinned UILabel's `Bottom,Leading` and `Trailing` edges to `UITableViewCell` contentsView.

Now problem is that when i tap `UITableViewCell` it does not resize `UILabel` and also does not adjust the `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my code for the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  MYCustomCell *cell = (MYCustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.descriptionLbl.text = @"This is my text";
  [cell layoutSubviews];
}
```

Similarly

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MYCustomCell *cell = (MYCustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.descriptionLbl.text = @"";
  [cell layoutSubviews];
}
```

Here is the layoutSubViews of my Custom Cell

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  self.descriptionLbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
  self.descriptionLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
  [self.descriptionLbl sizeToFit];
  if (self.descriptionLbl.text.length > 0){
    self.descriptionLbl.frame  = CGRectMake(self.descriptionLbl.frame.origin.x, self.descriptionLbl.frame.origin.y, self.descriptionLbl.frame.size.width, 50); // Here the size will be calculated more accurately later
  }
}
```

Just a note that i am not setting the height of the `UITableViewCell` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you've to manually manage autolayout constraints when only button is visible and after clicking text will be visible.
I've prepared a demo for that which you can found here.

**https://github.com/rushisangani/TableViewCellExpand**

Please refer storyboard constraints for TableViewCell and manage that wisely.

Comment: Hi, It seems to work. Thanks but i want to understand how you are using priority of the height constraint to show and hide it. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Yes, basically you have to set priority low for view you want to collapse. as well as subviews of that view.

Comment: Can you tell me some documentation where its mentioned that or there is some other trick you came up with. I am still unable to know how the priority is used to collapse it.

Comment: You need to understand Compression Resistance and Content Hugging priority in autolayout. Here is only one example from where you can learn things. http://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real

Comment: Yes i understand them. But the outlet that you have created here. Is it for content Hugging or compression resistance priority?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102483/discussion-between-iosenthusiatic-and-madu).

Comment: Hi @iOSEnthusiatic. Now i understand your solution. Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you need to do this your -viewdidLoad

```
[_tableview setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
[_tableview setEstimatedRowHeight:44];
```

**UITableViewAutomaticDimension** says your cell height is dynamic and **setEstimatedRowHeight** let your scroll height calculated

Comment: top view (button) top margin must be aligned with contentView's topmargin and bottom view's (label) bottom margin must be aligned with contentView's bottom margin. Ensure this

Comment: Does it make any difference? I mean i already have my Button.top = contentView.top and similarly label.bottom = contentView.bottom

Answer (score 0):

When setting up dynamically sized views in table view cells, it's really important that you set up **all** the constraints properly. Most common mistake developers do is to omit the bottom vertical constraint on the cell.

To get a more detailed explanation of how to set up dynamically resized UILabels in custom UITableViewCells, check out a post I wrote right [here](http://candycode.io/how-to-correctly-set-up-uilabels-with-auto-layout-on-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 2.0 :***

**Add this :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

or

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

In case of Table View Controller, use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```